# TextInput Bubble doesn't stay on long touch: Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

When I long touch a TextInput on android app (build via Kivy), the bubble appears for a second and then disappears.

I'm getting my head around with the TextInput of Kivy and learning how it works. I added a simple TextInput in kivy app and tried to paste something from my clipboard. When I long press on the TextInput, the android bubble appears for only a second (or maybe less than that) and then disappears.

I read on this forum regarding the `use_bubble: True`

I added this to my .kv file as well but doesn't work either.

Please help.

```
Label:
    text:"Enter text to be encoded"
TextInput:
    id:obox
    use_bubble:True
    foreground_color:(1,0,0,1)
    multiline:True
    on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): self.text = ""
```

Comment: can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: is there no on who can assist on this ??

Answer (score 2):

add below code in your main.py file

```
class CustomTextInput(TextInput):
    def _hide_cut_copy_paste(self, win=None):
        bubble = self._bubble
        if not bubble:
            return
        #bubble_hide()
```

use CustomTextInput in .kv file instead of TextInput

Answer (score 0):

The closing of the bubble can have several reasons:

- a key press (only interesting keys like Escape)
- mouse or touch movement, scroll or button press
- changing of the cursor position in your textinput widget
- changing the focus (either to the textinput or any other widget)

I'd recommend to use a debugger putting a breakpoint on the
`_hide_cut_copy_paste` method of the `TextInput` widget for to
determine which reason is closing the bubble.